# JFrame, toFront(), ActionListener

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jdialog

My problem is this. I got this two windows that work together and move together.
[image]

[image]

However if I then open broweser or something that will go in front of the screen, and then I try to show my program in front by clicking it on taskbar, then only one window goes in front. Dialog is in the back and I dont know how to fixe it.

I know there is function ToFront() however I stil dont know how to use it in this scenario.

Comment: Create a MenuItem for the second window in the main, that'll either switch between a basic calculator and advanced. (e.g. Windows Calculator -> Scientific etc)

Comment: would it fix the problem or is it just esthetic's suggestion?

Comment: I'm currently a college student myself, and I've done plenty of calculators in the past two years, easiest would be to implement a MenuItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem, as VGR already said... Non-modal Dialog will follow it's parent:

```
public class FocusMain extends JFrame {

    private static FocusMain frame;
    private static JDialog dialog;
    private JCheckBox checkBox;

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new FocusMain();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        dialog = new JDialog(frame);
        dialog.setSize(100, 100);
    }

    public FocusMain() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        checkBox = new JCheckBox("show dialog");
        checkBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
                    dialog.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    dialog.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(checkBox);
    }
 }
```

With extended JDialog you will need to pass the parent frame through the constructor and if your constructor looks like this: `public ExtendedJDialog(JFrame parentFrame)` then you can connect it with it's parent frame with `super(parentFrame);` as the first line in your constructor...

```
 public class FocusMain extends JFrame {

    private static FocusMain frame;
    private static FocusDialog dialog;
    private JCheckBox checkBox;

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new FocusMain();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        dialog = new FocusDialog(frame);
    }

    public FocusMain() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        checkBox = new JCheckBox("show dialog");
        checkBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
                    dialog.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    dialog.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(checkBox);
    }
 }
```

and extended JDialog

```
 public class FocusDialog extends JDialog {

    public FocusDialog(JFrame parentFrame) {
        super(parentFrame);
        setSize(100, 100);
    }
 }
```

if you need the dialog to block the parent, use `super(parentFrame, true);`

Comment: I think I know what is the problem. This smaller window is a Jpanel, however ive made it in another class and its extension of JDialog.
     `public class FunkcjeMatematyczne extends javax.swing.JDialog`

what I didnt do, and what i dont know how to do is how to do this:
    `dialog = new JDialog(frame_owner);`

that is set the dialog owner. Is it even possible in extended class..?

Comment: You can do that in the extended class with `super(parentFrame);` I'll edit my answer to include this...

Comment: When I put this `super(Okno_Glowne);` in constructor of my extended JDialog class then I get message "cannot reference Okno_Glowne before supertype constructor has been called". Ps. Okno_Glowne is an extension of JFrame...

Comment: then you have to pass `okno` to `super()` not `Okno_Glowne` because that's the variable name after it is passed to constructor. try with `super(okno);`

Comment: I feel lazy I didnt check it.  It helped!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating two JFrames, create a JFrame for your main window and create all other windows as non-modal JDialogs, with the JFrame as their owner.  This will cause them to be stacked as a single group;  whenever the user brings one to the front, all are brought to the front.

Comment: smaller window is JDialog.